# How to convert object into Number or string using FormattedNumber to render in react tooltip using REACTJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, tooltip, react-intl

I am trying to make a application which supports multi language 
    for this Im using react-intl which translates the data. While 
    doing this Im facing a problem that when I am trying to translate 
    it returns me as [OBJECT OBJECT] but im expecting a number or 
    string.

I am using "react-intl": "2.7.2" for translation , "react-tooltip": "3.10.0", for rendering tooltip value

Tooltip Code. In this i want tooltip value to be Transalted into different language numberformat

```
<div className="column number" 
 data-tip={ <FormattedNumber value= {1234234545465655} />}>
 1234234545465655
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4gjg.png)

Please find the above image for reference

I am getting output as [OBJECT OBJECT]

Source Code:

```
import { FormattedMessage,FormattedNumber,formatNumber,injectIntl } from 'react-intl';
    const TDSHighlights = ({
      GlobalData,
      currencySymbol,
      currency,
      props,
    }) => (
         {console.log(props)}
         <div className="column number" 
                  data-tip={num}>
          Tooltip value
         </div>

        );
    export default injectIntl(TDSHighlights);
```

Added sample code while printing props data not getting props value

Answer (score 0):

FormattedNumber is a component that tries to render a span (or other elements) to the page. If you just want a function you can call to return a string, instead use [formatNumber](https://github.com/formatjs/react-intl/blob/master/docs/API.md#formatnumber)

```
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl';


const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  const num = props.formatNumber(1234);
  //    or with options, as in:
  // const num = props.formatNumber(1234, { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
  return (
    <div className= column number" data-tip={num}>
      Tooltip value
    </div>
  );
}

export default injectIntl(SomeComponent);
```

Comment: Oops, it looks like formatNumber has to be passed in as a prop, rather than imported directly. I've updated my example.

Comment: const num = this.props.formatNumber(1234);

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
@Nicholas Tower

Comment: Are you using a class component or a functional component?

Comment: am using functional component

Comment: Then the syntax for class components will of course not work for you. I've converted my example to a functional component.

Comment: i have tried class component  also not working , getting same error @Nicholas Tower

Comment: If you have some code you'd like me to help debug, please share it. Otherwise, i'm sorry my solution didn't work for you.

Comment: Added sample code in the question , please check @Nicholas Tower

Comment: What i called `props` is the entire props object. You're using destructuring to pluck individual properties off of props. It's perfectly fine if you want to use destructuring, you just need to update your variable names to match. `const TDSHighlights = ({ GlobalData, currencySymbol, currency, formatNumber }) => {`